# passing bash array elements to awk regex inside loop

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to search through a file using awk, by looping over elements of a bash array. This is what I'm currently doing

```
myarray[1] = 441
myarray[2] = 123

for i in "${myarray[@]}"
do
awk '{if ($4 == '"$i"') print $0}' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
done
```

Is it possible to access elements of a bash array in awk in this way?

Comment: You aren't accessing an array element there. You are accessing a normal shell variable. And yes, that works just fine assuming you quote the string in the awk context (i.e.  you need `"'"$i"'"` instead of just `'"$i"'`).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, i've replaced "'"$i"'" with "441" which I know is in the file, and this works. So I think the problem is still with defining the element in the loop.

Comment: Once the quoting is fixed, note that `awk` is still not "accessing shell variables".  Rather, you are using the value of a shell variable in a string that you pass to awk.  The value of `$i` is expanded by the shell before the `awk` command is executed.

Comment: You have an extra single quote before the close-quote in your expansion`"${myarray[@]}'"` which could be what's messing you up.

Comment: I've edited out the extra single quote, that wasn't what was messing me up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the right way to pass a shell variable (or BASH array element) to awk. Use it with `-v` option:

```
myarray=(441 123)

for i in "${myarray[@]}'"; do
   awk -v i="$i" '$4 == i' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
done
```

- `-v i="$i"` makes shell variable `$i` available inside `awk` as an awk variable `i`
- `$4 == i` is equivalent of `{if ($4 == i) print $0}` since `print $0` is the default action

Comment: Just a small note that use `>> newfile.txt` instead of `> newfile.txt` otherwise you will see output of last awk command only.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I can replace the i in '$4 == i' with 441 and get the ouput, but it doesn't recognize the i

Comment: That was what was doing it! the >> . Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you mean `awk -v i="441" '$4 == i' myfile.txt` doesn't work but `awk '$4 == 441' myfile.txt` works?

Comment: You could also just move the `> newfile.txt` from the `awk` to the `done` so the file is only written once instead of written and then appended each time.

Comment: @tclarke something to consider - rather than writing a shell loop, just pass the whole array contents to awk at once and let it do everything else.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with Ed. I just wrote this answer to showcase right way of accessing shell variable inside awk. But if I have to write the script I would definitely call awk once and without loop.

Comment: @TomFenech: Only problem with that approach is if array elements contain strings with spaces and newlines then `echo ${my_array[@]}` will fail to be parsed inside awk correctly. Though it should work for array wit numbers only.

Comment: @anubhava, i think i may [have contrived a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25450637/753731) to deal with the embedded space problem

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for a bash loop; you can do the whole thing in awk:

```
my_array=(441 123)
awk -varr="${my_array[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(arr,a); for(i in a)b[a[i]]} $4 in b' file
```

The contents of the shell array are passed to awk as a single string, with a space in between each element. `split` is used to create an awk array from the string. Array `a` looks like this:

```
a[1]=441; a[2]=123
```

The `for` loop creates an array `b` with two keys, `b[441]` and `b[123]`.

Lines are printed when the 4th column matches one of the array keys.

Bear in mind that this approach fails when the elements in the array contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid looping through the `bash` array elements externally. In the following, the array elements are passed at one shot to `awk` and accessed within `awk` using `ARGV`. Also, there's no reason why `awk` cannot write to the output file directly

```
awk -v len="${#myarray[@]}" '
BEGIN{t=ARGC; ARGC-=len; for(i=2; i<t; ++i) b[ARGV[i]]++ };
$4 in b { print > "newfile.txt"}' myfile.txt  "${myarray[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also construct an awk regex:

```
myarray=(441 123)
regex=$(IFS=\|;echo "^(${myarray[*]})\$")
awk -v regex="$regex" '$4 ~ regex' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

However, do be careful if there are metacharacters (i.e. '*', '\', '?' etc) in any element of the array.